# Dreamweaver style checkout in an IDE

Tags: php, ide, dreamweaver

I'm a budding php developer and my company requires that I use Dreamweaver to check files in and out from the server.  This is really the only feature of Dreamweaver that I like.  It's super easy to get a fresh copy of a file from the server and keep track of who has a file etc.  But as an IDE it leaves tons to be desired.  Obviously I could use Dreamweaver to check out the files and then edit them in another tool, but I'd rather not.  I can't be the first person to be in this situation, What should I be using?  Ecplipse?  NetBeans? has someone written a plugin for something for this?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's your beef with Dreamweaver? There are arguments to be made for a variety of IDEs, but honestly DW doesn't do a bad job with PHP (it does syntax highlighting, variable and function-prompting, includes, real-time syntax error highlighting etc etc). What are you trying to get out of an IDE?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to look at a source control solution, such as [Git](http://git-scm.com/).